# Ordering a mysql table by date when the column is declared varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort a table by date (descending), but all columns in the table are `varchar`, so I need to manipulate the data on the fly for sorting it correctly.

```
date        sales
10/09/2014  100
13/09/2014  250
30/08/2014  200
```

Is that possible without altering the table? So the result will be like below, newest dates first?

```
date        sales
13/09/2014  250
10/09/2014  100
30/08/2014  200
```

Like pseudocode

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY (CONCAT(REGEXP(date, '[0-9]{4}'), 
REGEXP(date, '/[0-9]{2}/'), REGEXP(date, '^[0-9]{4}/')) DESC
```

I think I need to use `substring_index` somehow, because `regexp` just returns 1 or 0, not the actual value found.

Comment: MySQL has a number of Date & Time functions that could help with this, but the real solution is to redesign your tables so that the columns have appropriate data types. Even if you get past this problem, poor design __will__ bite you again.

Comment: If this column were stored as a `DATE` rather than a `VARCHAR`, then MySQL would be able to use an **index** for the ORDER BY operation, returning rows in order, rather than requiring a "Using filesort" operation on a value derived from an expression. The same principle applies to range predicates, getting all rows for a month... with a DATE column we can write a query that enables an index range scan operation, with the VARCHAR column like this, it will require an expression to be evaluated for every flipping row in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your `varchar`-stored date objects into `DATE` objects, then use them to order.

This you can do on the fly like so

```
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d/%m/%Y') DESC
```

But performance is going to be horrible.  For best results store your dates in a `DATE` column in your table.

Answer (score 2):

you can use STR_TO_DATE

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') desc,
sales desc
```